# Oracle Database installation stuck at 'Starting Oracle Configuration Assistant'

Tags: windows, oracle, virtual-machine

I am installing Oracle 19c (19.3) for Microsoft Windows x64 (64-bit) in VM. It is stuck at 44%. I checked the details and there is a warning message saying that there isn't enough memory. Before the installation, I checked my VM memory and storage. There is more than enough memory and storage. Before installing, Oracle runs a check and there succeeded, no failed. Despite all that, the installation still stuck.

This is the warning message:

```
[WARNING] [DBT-11209] Current available memory is less than the required available memory (1,638MB) for creating the database.
CAUSE: Following nodes do not have required available memory :Node:ec2amaz-97eqf7fAvailable memory:1.4685GB (1539828.0KB)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle 19c installation error : \[INS-35179\] Current available memory is less than the required available memory (1,597MB) for creating DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64283161/oracle-19c-installation-error-ins-35179-current-available-memory-is-less-tha)

Answer (score 0):

Please see

https://github.com/oracle/vagrant-projects/issues/241

If it is a single instance install, please consider to create the scripts with DBCA instead using DBCA - gives you more control whats going on splitting the shell script calling the separate SQL files

Comment: What are some alternative to resolving this issue? Unfortunately, I don't know vagrant.

Answer (score 0):

Please see Helmut Hutzlers Blog

https://www.hhutzler.de/blog/start-gimr-database-fails-12-2-installation/

He was member of same team then me before Oracle shutdown Software Support in Europe in March 2016. He got more then 25 years experiance - In a couple of days I will leave Oracle, too. Last one swiches the light bulbs off.