# Oracle 19c installation error : [INS-35179] Current available memory is less than the required available memory (1,597MB) for creating DB

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

I am trying to install the oracle 19c and during installation met with a memory related issue " [INS-35179] Current available memory is less than the required available memory (6,537MB) for creating DB". I double checked all the prerequisites like over `2GB free RAM, 10 GB free space on hard disk drive`,  I tried looking up for a solution to this issue but have not got a clue as to what i need to do to resolve this issue. This is the first time i am trying to install oracle 13c. Here is the attached image of this issue.

[image]

Comment: The number in the error message in your image is different to the number in your question text, and much higher than the 2GB you said you checked for.

Comment: yes,  i edited it and made it same. But how to resolve the error in question

Comment: Is this an install on a desktop? The installer often chooses a large default amount of memory for PGA and SGA, you may want to choose the Advanced installation and reduce the memory settings.

Comment: yes it is on my windows desktop

Answer (score 7):

My solution to this is to close all applications(especially Chrome). Try to end those heavy tasks (those eaten up a lot of RAM) in Task Manager so that your RAM has enough space for the downloading to start.
[image]

Comment: I don't imagine this answer was the easier one and really helpful.

Comment: This actually works, Theres an aplication called Mem reduct, with that you can free some ram https://memreduct.org/

Answer (score 0):

**Simply proceed by clicking 'ok'**, even if it shows error INS-35179, I did the same and then the Software got installed without any Interruption, this works because we always have more storage in our C: Drive than the space shown in the error.